# Intellij Idea how can I specify colors for a specific file type?

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using a color theme that I am perfectly happy with, but I am dealing with a lot of ".impex" files that are unique to the Hybris platform. The IDE essentially sees them as text files. How can I add syntax coloring to these ".impex" files so the text is not just all one color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this plugin can help you.

[Syntax highlight for impex files](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525?pr=idea)

Besides, you can register a file pattern to a recognised file type: Preferences -> IDE Settings -> File Types.

Comment: Thank you.  The plugin didn't seem to work.  But I did figure out how to register the file pattern and add some keywords for syntax highlighting.  Do you know how I can register a semicolon so that it will change colors?  I tried ; by itself and also surrounded in double quotes and single quotes, but none of them did the trick.

Comment: @Lani1234 I am sorry I don't know how to use ; as a keyword.

Comment: I went back and tried the plugin again - I was trying to install it the wrong way before, which is why it didn't work.  Now that I installed it the right way, it is working.  Thanks for finding that.